# Firewall get slow download some CSS and JS files

Tags: firewall, javascript, css

Our company website is hosted on our infrastructure and external user can access it OK. 
However, when I try to access from our intranet, some CSS and JS files always take exactly 2 minutes to download, blocking site load until completely download, and it happens always with the same files. Even I add the entire URL of them in the firewall's whitelist, this behavior is the same. 
If I access the file, and I could reproduce this scenario ([see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3qG5.png)). 
What do I need to setup in the firewall to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

## Some tips for faster loading CSS/JS

- **Wherever possible try to load your JS files just before your closing `</body>` tag.** This makes it so the page can start displaying before your JS finishes loading.
- **Use `async` JS loading.** If the JS is a file that takes a very long time or is a big download it might be a candidate for loading `async` instead. Here's some info on how to [use optimizely to do asynchronous JS loading](https://help.optimizely.com/Set_Up_Optimizely/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_snippet_loading). If that JS is needed right away you still have to solve that issue but at least you could use async in the meantime while you work out the details.
- **Put public assets in your root web directory**
- **Minify** your CSS and JS code where applicable
- **Serve assets over a CDN** (Content Delivery Network) so the files load from someone else's servers, which most typically is faster and more reliable. If you're using a common library asset like jQuery, you can find them already uploaded to a CDN and freely usable. Just insert something like this just before your closing `</body>` tag... `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Here's where I got that [CDN link info](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/).

Also, here at least one [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717415/css-and-js-files-take-too-long-to-download) that might be helpful.